# Cocos2D Box2D errors?

Tags: ios, error-handling, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have been trying to upgrade my Cocos2D project from 1.1 to 2.0 but I have run into odd errors that no one else seems to have when I google them.

I get Semantic Issue: Redefinition of b2Color and b2Draw. I have included my header search paths and clicked on the little box next to it but that seems to make no difference.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah i just had a similar problem today. I'll describe the whole process of making Box2d work with new project, cause i was solving this half of the day. First i had to put in the .pch file:
`#ifdef __cplusplus
   #import "Box2D.h"
 #endif`

and in the header search paths i just put ".", then under build settings(of the project) in Other C flags:
-DTARGET_OS_IPHONE

then in the draw.h and timer.h (it's like they forgot, cause in the other files it's there)
at the top:
`#ifndef name
 #define name`

at the bottom
`#endif`

And of course you have to extend your .m files to .mm if you're importing box2d anywhere.

Hope that helped you or anybody else, it did it for me.

Comment: Yea I also figured out the endif fix. I will change my project with your .pch trick though since thats easier than header search paths! :)